# User registration form in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, session, menu

I am trying to make a user registration form in Android using SQLite in which login and logout operations will be performed. I want to maintain the session when the user logs in, then when he clicks the logout button:

How do I add a logout menu option in the menu dynamically in place of the login option menu?

In the net, they are maintaining a session using shared preferences, but I'm storing the username and password in an SQLite database.

So, how would I maintain a session if I'm using SQLite?

Comment: when user press logout button, delete username and password from sqlite. by the way, correct way to store session is to use sharedpreferences.

Comment: see below https://codezone4.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/android-login-system-using-sqlite/

Comment: Have you heard about User Account Manager?

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik if i use sharedpreferences for storing user and password. Then how to store other details should i use sharedpreferences too for them . Because i want to work with sqlite.I m new in android.

Comment: @Ashanアシャン Thanks for giving me this link but the in the code they did'nt manage user session.

Comment: @JennyGomez Yes, you can use sharedpreferences for storing all the user information. When user clicks logout button remove sharedpreferences and when clicks login button, fetch data from sqlite and again store to sharedpreferences, Thus this is the correct way to maintain sessions.

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik Thanks .

Comment: @JennyGomez welcome and can you do one thing for me?

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik  What can i do for u?

Comment: @JennyGomez I am making one answer to your question, you just upvote it and mark correct green sign.It will also help you to increase reputation.

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sharedpreferences for storing all the user information. When user clicks logout button remove sharedpreferences and when clicks login button, fetch data from sqlite and again store to sharedpreferences, Thus this is the correct way to maintain sessions.

Comment: i fetched username and password from sqlite but when I am storing into SharedPreferences value are overwiting

Comment: Which values are overwriting? Values of sharedpref or values of sqlite?

Comment: values in sharedpreference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910228/how-to-write-data-to-shared-preferences-which-is-fetched-from-sqlite.  I am giving u this this in which i am getting problem..